# Is there a way to get the element 1 before/after upper indexing limit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, datetimeindex

I have a Dataframe with Timeindex and a Timeindex till which I want to slice the dataframe.

```
df[:upper_Timeindex_Timevalue]
```

The Question:

How do I get the element before this "limiting-index"?

```
df[:upper_Timeindex_Timevalue -1] # this wouldnt work this way bc timevalue +1 is not the next in dataframe
```

And how do I get the element after this "limiting-index"?

```
df[:upper_Timeindex_Timevalue +1] # this wouldnt work this way bc timevalue +1 is not the next in dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.index < upper_Timeindex_Timevalue].last()
```

or

```
df.loc[df.index > lower_Timeindex_TimeValue].first()
```